# update one or more fields inside of a document, without updating all the fields

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a feature in my program where I have to enter the user's details such as the user's age, height, and weight. This data will be stored in Firestore.

this is how the user will input their details

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class account_information extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "TAG";
    EditText et_age, et_height, et_weight;
    Button btn_create;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    String userID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_information);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        et_age = findViewById(R.id.et_age);
        et_height = findViewById(R.id.et_height);
        et_weight = findViewById(R.id.et_weight);
        btn_create = findViewById(R.id.btn_create);




        btn_create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String age = et_age.getText().toString().trim();
                String height = et_height.getText().toString().trim();
                String weight = et_weight.getText().toString().trim();


                if(age.isEmpty()){
                    et_age.setError("Age is mandatory");
                    et_age.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if(height.isEmpty()){
                    et_height.setError("Height is mandatory");
                    et_height.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if(weight.isEmpty()){
                    et_weight.setError("Weight is mandatory");
                    et_weight.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }


                userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("userDetail").document(userID);
                Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                user.put("Age",age);
                user.put("Height",height);
                user.put("Weight",weight);
                user.put("UserId", userID);

                        documentReference.set(user)
                        .addOnSuccessListener((OnSuccessListener) (aVoid) -> {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user Detail is created for "+ userID);
                            startActivity(new Intent(account_information.this, MainActivity.class));
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure"+ e.toString());

                    }

                });

            }
        });

    }
}
```

And this is how it will store in firebase

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBbN1.jpg

However, when the user decides to update their profile (for example his weight) the rest of the input will pass an empty string at the firebase

like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8iIz.jpg

And this is how the user can update their details

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;


import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class UpdateProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "TAG";
    EditText et_age, et_height, et_weight;
    Button btn_update;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore mStore;
    String userID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_profile);

        et_age = findViewById(R.id.et_age);
        et_height = findViewById(R.id.et_height);
        et_weight = findViewById(R.id.et_weight);

        btn_update = findViewById(R.id.btn_update);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        btn_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String age = et_age.getText().toString().trim();
                String height = et_height.getText().toString().trim();
                String weight = et_weight.getText().toString().trim();


                userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DocumentReference documentReference = mStore.collection("userDetail").document(userID);
                documentReference
                .update("Age",age, "Height",height, "Weight",weight)
                 .addOnSuccessListener((OnSuccessListener) (aVoid) -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user Detail is created for "+ userID);
                     startActivity(new Intent(UpdateProfile.this, MainActivity.class));
                 }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure"+ e.toString());

                    }

                });


        }


    });


    }}
```

Update: I've tried the method of @zen_of_kermit but I got the same problem, maybe there's something in the code that I've missed

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;


import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UpdateProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "TAG";
    EditText et_age, et_height, et_weight;
    Button btn_update;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore mStore;
    String userID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_profile);

        et_age = findViewById(R.id.et_age);
        et_height = findViewById(R.id.et_height);
        et_weight = findViewById(R.id.et_weight);

        btn_update = findViewById(R.id.btn_update);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();



        btn_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                String age = et_age.getText().toString().trim();
                String height = et_height.getText().toString().trim();
                String weight = et_weight.getText().toString().trim();

                userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DocumentReference documentReference = mStore.collection("userDetail").document(userID);
                Map<String, Object> dataToUpdateMap = new HashMap<>();
                if (isValidAndChanged(documentReference, "Age", age)) {
                    dataToUpdateMap.put("Age", age);
                }
                if (isValidAndChanged(documentReference, "Height", height)) {
                    dataToUpdateMap.put("Height", height);
                }
                if (isValidAndChanged(documentReference, "Weight", weight)) {
                    dataToUpdateMap.put("Weight", weight);
                }
                documentReference.update(dataToUpdateMap).addOnSuccessListener((OnSuccessListener) (aVoid) -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user Detail is created for "+ userID);
                    startActivity(new Intent(UpdateProfile.this, readProfileData.class));
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure"+ e.toString());

                    }

                });


            }


        });



    }
            boolean isValidAndChanged(DocumentReference docRef, String key, Object value) {
            return true;
            }





        }
```

Comment: I can't tell if you're trolling or not. Your function `isValidAndChanged` is always returning true... You need to *actually* check the existing values and as Alex similarly pointed out, make sure they are not empty strings (i.e. valid) and different from what is already stored remotely.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing all three fields (age, height, weight) without checking if they are valid or contain changes to the existing data. You should make those checks before calling update, similar to how you did in the create function.

For example, create a function to check if new data is valid and different than old data:

```
boolean isValidAndChanged(DocumentReference docRef, String key, String value) {
    // TODO get snapshot of data and compare to new value
}
```

And then use that to update (passing a `Map` to `update` instead of var-args):

```
    String age = et_age.getText().toString().trim();
    String height = et_height.getText().toString().trim();
    String weight = et_weight.getText().toString().trim();

    userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DocumentReference documentReference = mStore.collection("userDetail").document(userID);
    Map<String, String> dataToUpdateMap = new HashMap<>();
    if (isValidAndChanged(documentReference, "Age", age)) {
        dataToUpdateMap.put("Age", age);
    }
    if (isValidAndChanged(documentReference, "Height", height)) {
        dataToUpdateMap.put("Height", height);
    }
    if (isValidAndChanged(documentReference, "Weight", weight)) {
        dataToUpdateMap.put("Weight", weight);
    }
    documentReference.update(dataToUpdateMap)
    // ...
```

Also, best practice is to use constants instead of passing magic strings around all over your code (e.g. "Age" becomes `AGE`.)

Comment: I can make a condition that require the user to enter a value but that would make every time the user wants to update a field, he has to input all the fields @zen_of_kermit

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do that, you just need to not pass in unchanged/invalid values to the Firebase update call.

Comment: how can I do it ? @zen_of_kermit

Comment: I added a code example to hopefully explain it better. Good luck with your project.

Comment: it give me the same problem, can you check the code above because I've added your take on it @zen_of_kermit

Answer (score 0):

You're getting all the data overwritten because you're passing empty strings to the update() method. Firestore can indeed [hold null values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), but the values of `Age` and `Height` after the update are not null, but empty strings.

If you want to update a single field and leave the other ones untouched, then you should simply pass to the update() method only values for the fields you need to update. In code, it should look like this:

```
documentReference.update("Weight", weight).addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
```

Comment: You mean that I need to call the method update three times? @Alex_Mamo

Comment: No, If you have to update all three fields, then it's mandatory to make sure you pass valid values to the `Age` and `Height`. Otherize it will empty strings. If you only want to update on, pass a single value.

Comment: then how to pass the previous values The I've already entered ? @Alex_Mamo

Comment: I've added an update of the code @Alex_Mamo

Comment: There is **no** need to add the previous values to the update operation since you don't update them. You **only** need to add what you update. The other values will remain untouched. Give it a try, and tell me if it works.

Comment: I don't understand to be honest @Alex_Mamo

Comment: To update only the "Weight", you have to use `documentReference.update("Weight", weight)`. That's it. Nothing more. Have you even tried it?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: No I didn't but I get your point, but how about the other fields that the user wants to update, maybe the user want to update just two fields, or maybe all the fields @Alex_Mamo

Comment: In that case, perform the update for that particular field **only** when you have a value that is different than an empty string, right?

Comment: yes, but how can I do it, I thought of putting a condition that a field value cannot change if it pass an empty string @Alex_Mamo

Comment: Yes, sounds feasible. Or you can check the value of each field and call the update method only with fields that are not empty.

Comment: ok that seems right but can you write the code for me because I don't know how to do it @Alex_Mamo

Comment: That's something you have to do yourself. If you have a hard time implementing that, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow with [everything you have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information, regarding the initial issue?